# VSCode Remote extension suggests rebuild without changes

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

When developing with a devcontainer in VSCode (Docker Desktop), the VSCode Remote Extension sometimes asks for a rebuild although no file in the `.devcontainer` folder has changed.

Is this a bug or does the Extension checks if there are newer version of the used image or installed software?